# C - Create a save into a ppm file

Tags: c

I am quite novice in C and I want to generate a new ppm file called "vfork.ppm". My program compiles and the function "save()" is executed but no vfork.ppm generated. I guess this is because I haven't provide to the file a direct path but I do not know how to do it. The current location of my project is: desktop->project->main.c

```
 void save(){
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("vfork.ppm","w+");
        fputs("P3\n",fp);
        fputs("64 64\n",fp);
        fputs("255\n",fp);
        for(int i =0; i < 64;i++){
            for(int j =0; j < 64*3; j++){
                fprintf(fp,"%d",colors[i][j]);
                fputs(" ",fp);
            }
            fputs("\n",fp);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

Comment: check 1) the current path 2) `fp` value != `NULL` if file could not be created

Comment: How do you write the first steep? thanks